# Cal license in case of three tier applications

Tags: sql, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I have three tier solution viz   **database <-> Application <-> Client**

My application server query to database and prepares XMLs in pre defined time intervals and sends these xmls to the cleint. On the client side we have a presenatation apps which does the presentation.Now I have 5 clients then do i need to have 5 CAL license OR 1 CAl license?

Comment: I'm not a sysadmin guy, but the idea of having to pay a license for each person accessing your database is just so retarded. I would assume you're paying for the database already, why do assholes charge for your ACCESSING your database?

Comment: Because otherwise the database would cost more? Retarded arrogantt and stupid admins obviously lack the capability to add 1+1 these days.

Answer (score 2):

0 CAl. Maybe 1. Depends how your application accesses the data. Because the clients never access the database at all - this is pretty much a regular export job. Once exported - the CAL does not count anymore. The trick here is that the export is not triggered by the user. This is similar than exporting a catalog into HTML via a tool and then having the web server server the static HTML.

Note that this does not mean you do not need other CAL's for other scenarios (like somehow to get the data INTO the database).